# Trying to use Jquery and Ajax to swap out page content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to preface my question with some history so you know what and who you are dealing with. I am a 75 year old just retired house painter who is building just this one website so that I can sell some of the stuff that I have done for many years as a hobby. I have a decent understanding of HTML and CSS and a lesser knowledge of PHP from browsing the internet. JavaScript knowledge is zilch.

This is an include file for the content in one of the sections of my website. It works fine with just one Mysqli query and no JavaScript, but with a lot of products to list I would like to swap the content so I wouldn't have to add more pages. The JavaScript is borrowed from a tutorial by Adam Khoury and I just plugged in my information to it.

My question is, can I use the LIMIT clause as a mechanism to swap the content of the page as I tried within the code below? At this point I am getting this error.

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
boolean given in C:\wamp\www\elkcreek\includes\cabscontent1.php on line 37.
```

This line is:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Thanks in advance for any help or just for reading this diatribe.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<?php
require "scripts/connect_to_copy.php";

$contentVar = '';
$products = '';
$sql = '';

if (isset($_POST['contentVar'])) {$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];}

if ($contentVar == "con1")
{
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM cabs ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 4" );
}
else if ($contentVar == "con2")
{
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM cabs ORDER BY id LIMIT 4, 8");
}
else if ($contentVar == "con3")
{
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM cabs ORDER BY id LIMIT 8, 12");
}

$result = mysql_query($sql)

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $pages = $row["pages"];
    $left_image = $row["left_image"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $ordering_number = $row["ordering_number"];
    $sold = $row["sold"];

    $products .=
    '<div class="product">
        <div class="product_pictures"><a href="' . $pages . '">
            <img src="' . $left_image . '" alt="cabochon" width="150" height="200"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="product_name"><h3>' . $product_name . '</h3></div>
        <div class="price">$' . $price . '</div>
        <div class="order_number">Order# C' . $ordering_number . '</div>
        <div class="sold">' . $sold . '</div>
    </div>';
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
function swapContent(cv) {
    $(".product").html('<img src="loader.gif"/>').show();
    var url = "cabscontent1.php?";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
        $(".product").html(data).show();
    });
}
</script>

<div class="desc">CLICK ON PICTURES FOR LARGER PICTURES  -  DESCRIPTIONS
</div>

<div class="more_cabs">MORE CABS
    <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con1');">1</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con2');">2</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con3');">3</a>
</div>

<div class="product_column"><?php echo $products; ?></div>
```

Comment: Delete  this line $result = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: Typo? In the query you're using the mysql lib, later the mysqli lib.

Comment: Also update this line while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)), to : while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))

Comment: Robert  Did what you said and now get this error:  Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\wamp\www\elkcreek\includes\cabscontent1.php on line 37

Comment: Please don't put the solution into the question because then the question can no longer be understood. Please put the solution into an answer.

Comment: honk:  Changed it back to original.  Totally new at this. Thanks